# excel vba, add range name for ADA compliance

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add range names to make the spreadsheet ADA compliant. I have tried the code below;

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="On_Draft_List_D", RefersToR1C1:=("Sheet1!R1C1:R" & LastRow - 35 & "C1")
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("On_Draft_List_D").Comment = ""
```

While the entry does appear in the Name Manager, it doesn't appear in the Name Box on the spreadsheet. I have been unsuccessful with my internet searches and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I appreciate any help you could give me.

Comment: So your saying it doesn't appear in the dropdown menu where the cell name is placed?

Comment: Check RefersToR1C1 refers to the right range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your R1C1 reference is not valid I think, which is why it will not show up. I tested your code and had the same issue. Setting the range explicitly like:

```
Dim cell As Range
Set cell = Range("A1:B3")
ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="On_Draft_List_D", RefersTo:=cell
ActiveWorkbook.Names("On_Draft_List_D").Comment = ""
```

works much better. The RefersTo argument is probably easier to use, and by setting the range outside of the .Add call you can make selecting the correct range much easier

Comment: I setup the R1C1 reference like that because the same code runs on several worksheets of differing lengths. There are footnotes at the bottom of each sheet that have their own range name, which is why I used the LastRow - 35. Iwill try setting the range to a variable as you suggest and get back to you.

Comment: you can still use the LastRow-35 part, just do something like `"A1:C" & (LastRow-35)` and that will give you the desired range, changing "A", "C", and "1" as needed

Comment: No worries, its one of those little things that's really useful! If you could accept the answer that'd be great :)